# Eliminating the Parameter t to find the xy equation of curve along which the particle moves.

Tags: calculus, parametric

Currently studying for finals and came along this question.

```
Eliminate the parameter $t$ to find the $x-y$ equation of
the curve along which the particle moves.
x = 3cos(t)
y = 2sin(t)
```

**What I have done so far:**

Knowing $\sin^2(t) + cos^2(t)=1$, I wanted to give each a value.
$$\frac{x}{3} = \frac{3\cos (t)}{3}$$
$$\implies\cos(t)= \frac{x}{3}$$

$$\frac{y}{2} = \frac{2\sin (t)}{2}$$
$$\implies\sin(t)= \frac{y}{2}$$

I then input the values of both $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ into the equation, so

$$\Big(\frac{y}{2}\Big)^2+\Big(\frac{x}{3}\Big)^2=1$$
$$\implies\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{9}=1$$

$\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{9}=1$ is what I got as my final answer, is that right? Trying to make sure I got the hang of parametric equations.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. This equation represents an ellipse centred at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

In the equation of a trajectory it is recomended to solve or for $x$ or for $y$.
Then, the final equation should be $y=\sqrt {4-\frac{4x^2}{9}}\ \Leftrightarrow  y= 2\sqrt {1-\frac{x^2}{9}} \ $ or $x=\sqrt {9-\frac{9y^2}{4}}\ \Leftrightarrow  x= 3\sqrt {1-\frac{y^2}{4}}$

But it depends on what you are asked to do. So your resolution is also correct and it gives us, in this case, a better understanding of the trajectory : it's the graph of an elipse.

Comment: okay that makes so much sense, thanks for your help man:)

Comment: “In the equation of a trajectory it is recomended [sic] to solve or [sic] for $x$ or for $y$.” Really? Why? The entire curve can’t be captured by either a function of $x$ or $y$, so doing this leaves out part of the curve.

Comment: I was refering to physical parametrical equations, where the variable t reffers to time. Normaly one particle can't be at two places at once, so solving to x or y is reccomended. In this case, I recognise it's not the most appropriate.